# WCF Class 'New' sub not exposed

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

My WCF service contains a class like:

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class MyClass
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property MyProperty As Integer
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property MyOtherProperty As Integer
    Private Property mTotal As Integer
    <DataMember()>
    Public ReadOnly Property Total As Integer
        Get
            Return mTotal
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New(prop1 As Integer, prop2 As Integer)
        mTotal = prop1 + prop2
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I try and access the service I can create a new ‘MyClass’ object but the ‘New’ sub isn't exposed so I can't provide the parameters and mTotal will never be populated. Is this a limitation or am I missing something?

Comment: It's a good idea to include parameterless constructors for `DataContract`s, and make your class make sense when that was called, because the constructors don't come over to the client's service reference code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameterized constructor is only available on the server side, you can't call it from the client.  You can add a function to your ServiceContract that calls that constructor and then returns the result.  It's been several years since I used VB, so forgive me if the syntax isn't quite right, but this should give you the right idea:

```
<OperationContract()>
Function CreateNewMyClass(prop1 As Integer, prop2 As Integer) as MyClass
```

The implementation would look something like this:

```
Function CreateNewMyClass(prop1 As Integer, prop2 As Integer) as MyClass
    Return New MyClass(prop1, prop2) 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

SOAP web services do not expose anything that's specific to OO or .NET. You cannot expose your constructors, indexers, events, or anything like that.

Even when you "expose" an `enum`, you aren't really exposing an `enum`: only a string type which can have one of several enumerated string values. There is no corresponding integer.

You also can't expose overloaded methods as such, nor generics.

Answer (score 0):

Update your class by adding another, parameterless constructor:

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class MyClass
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property MyProperty As Integer
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property MyOtherProperty As Integer
    Private Property mTotal As Integer
    <DataMember()>
    Public ReadOnly Property Total As Integer
        Get
            Return mTotal
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New(prop1 As Integer, prop2 As Integer)
        mTotal = prop1 + prop2
    End Sub

   Public Sub New()
     ' default constructor
   End Sub
End Class
```

VB will give you a default (parameterless) constructor if you don't explicitly define one, but since you created a constructor that takes in `prop1` and `prop2`, the parameterless constructor is gone unless you define one.

Comment: Just added the empty constructor and it doesn't appear to have made a difference.